# To or to be? Help. Thanks

Tags: american-english, british-english, infinitives, active-vs-passive

> 1. There is a lot of information to process.
> 2. There is a lot of information to be processed.

Any grammatical difference? Both feels the same to me.

Comment: Both **feel** (not "feels") the same to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'There is a lot of information to process.'
2. 'There is a lot of information to be processed.'

The subtle difference is that

1. stresses on the doer, and
2. stresses on the information.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a lot of information to process.

means: there is a lot of information and someone/somebody will process them (information).

On the other hand,

> There is a lot of information to be processed.

means: there is a lot of information and they (information) should be processed by someone/somebody.

I think you understand the difference.
First example is active,
second is passive.